# What is the size limit for SoundPool in Android?

Tags: android

Is there a size limit for `SoundPool` in Android ? In [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidMedia/article.html) article, it says the sounds played with SoundPool should not exceed **1MB** .

I need to play multiple sounds simultaneously, And at times, I may exceed the 1MB limit. can I rely on SoundPool for this? As I couldn't find an in depth guide on SoundPool, a clear Answer will be much appreciated :)

Comment: why don't you use the MediaPlayer if you have those concerns ?

Comment: Well, solutions to similar questions here points to use SoundPool, also some methods of SoundPool seems quite handy.

Comment: Does the 1 MB limit refer to a **single file** or is it **cumulative**?

Comment: Yes, that's also one thing i need clarified :) .

Answer (score 1):

SoundPool is very limited, yes it has hardcoded buffer size limit, and if you exceed it you will get silence with error in logcat. Also it is written in native cpp and it is hard to debug what happend. Different versions of Android have specific issues.

I have written SoundPoolCompat which uses AudioTrack under the hood. You could pass custom `bufferSize`, and all data within that buffer will be loaded into memory and played with small latency like SoundPool does. All data that exceed that `bufferSize` will be loaded on demand (which adds latency, similar to MediaPlayer).
Api is very similart to SoundPool, also it is added loading sound from Uri (for example gdrive). And there is playOnce method, all resources will be unloaded after file is played.
I use it in my apps insted of SoundPool and MediaPlayer as well.

```
implementation 'com.olekdia:sound-pool:3.0.2'
```

https://gitlab.com/olekdia/common/libraries/sound-pool